# Webpack Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

This is a first I see this with Webpack, I'm trying out LitElement and trying to query my shadowRoot with getElementByID but this completly kills webpack for some reason like it needs a loader to parse the value of this basic javascript functionality.

It should be said I use typescript, I have a small test case here:

### App.ts

```js
import { customElement, html, LitElement } from "lit-element";

@customElement("open-studio")
export class OpenStudio extends LitElement {
    
    async onClick() {
        const textarea = this.shadowRoot?.getElementById("file-content")
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <div>Open Studio</div>
            <button @click=${this.onClick}>Button</button>
            <textarea id="file-content"></textarea>
        `
    }
}
```

### Webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: 'file-loader' },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname,
      "public"),
    disableHostCheck: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
};
```

### Error thrown

```
app.ts:1 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:41)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| let OpenStudio = class OpenStudio extends lit_element_1.LitElement {
|     async onClick() {
>         const textarea = this.shadowRoot?.getElementById("file-content");
|     }
```

I've been looking up and down for the last few hours, but I can't find a solution to this, and I've never faced this before (In React), I doubt its a TypeScript or LitElements vs React issue, its more like a configuration of webpack I just don't know of or do not understand yet, does any one here have a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using typescript, but putting it in a file called .js therefore the ts-loader is not transpiling it, and the first time it hits something non-javascripty it dies.

Comment: Sorry this was a typo in the post, it is a .ts file

Comment: I am not happy with this explanation, but note that textarea is an official html tag name,  and the error takes place exactly at the last character of the word textarea so perhaps somehow this is interfering given whatever loader stack you are using. Makes no sense but it's the sort of thing I would change to see https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: I ended up swapping away from webpack and go with rollup, it seems also the community around LitElements and WebComponents are going that direction, so I ended up swapping before my codebade grew larger :)

Thanks you for your help tho @cefn